# What is the difference between host controller and process controller in JBoss EAP?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8, jboss6.x

In JBoss EAP two separate JVM's are included for management purposes.

- What is the difference between `HostController` and `ProcessController`?
- Why do they need separate management processes?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the ProcessController is a native executable that will only handle starting and checking for its child processes, while the ProcessController is a java executable that will handle the configuration, command interface, possibly host the management interface, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The HostController process is a server process that manages the exchanges between the Host and the domain controller. The process controller is there to manage the managed server processes on the Host.

Answer (score 1):

A **domain controller** is the central point from which the domain is controlled. It ensures that each server is configured according to the management policy of the domain. The domain controller is also a host controller.

A **host controller** is a physical or virtual host that interacts with the domain controller to control the lifecycle of the application server instances running on its host and to assist the domain controller to manage them. Each host can contain multiple server groups.

A **process controller** is a small, lightweight process that is responsible for spawning the host controller process and monitoring its lifecycle. If the host controller crashes, the process controller will restart it. It also starts server processes as directed by the host controller; however, it will not automatically restart server processes that crash.

Answer (score 0):

Host Controller - a JVM Process that has responsibility to carry out the configuration Sync between the the Managed Server and the Domain controller
Process Controller - a JVM Process that has Operational responsibility to carry out start/stop/restart life cycle of Managed Servers
Domain Controller - A Host Controller (JVM) that is designated and can act as Master Admin for the Domain configuration
Managed Server - Where the actual enterpirse javaee apps are deployed and server the client requests.